# Open and close a program every 6 hours

Tags: windows-xp

I have a program for Windows XP, let's call it *X*, that needs to run 24/7. The computer's always on. Every day the program *X* hangs up, maybe twice a day. And it uses too much RAM,  so I need to restart it manually. And it all happens on 10 computers every day.

Is there some way to make a script or an executable file to start the program, and reopen it again, and I could just change the time? For example, from 6h to 12h?

Comment: Purely anecdotal, but a professor of mine sold that "You have to restart this program every *x* hours" as a feature back when he just couldn't fix the program itself. Anyway, is there a way you could tell us what exactly that program is so we can maybe try to fix the *actual* error instead of constructing a workaround?

Comment: There are diffrent programmes, they change every month. The script should have the ability to add the patch manualy to programme...

Answer (score 1):

If you can't fix the issue with that application, thus preventing it from hanging up, you can called it using the Task Scheduler. When an application is started by the task scheduler, it can stop it latter on.

Task Scheduler gives you complete control of the lifetime of your App:

1. Open Scheduled Tasks:

   Click Start -> All Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools -> Scheduled Tasks.
2. Double-click Add Scheduled Task to start the Scheduled Task Wizard.
3. Setup and create your task.
4. After created, right click over it and select "Properties".
5. Select the second tab "schedule" and setup the repeat options.
6. Select the third tab "Settings" and setup the duration for it.

---

You can refer to [How To Schedule Tasks in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) for further instructions.